# spring form tag radiobutton select one of group

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have one question about spring tag form and radiobuttons. I have a task something like testing. User logged in and can choose some test. On the test page i'm using spring tag form and radiobuttons for answering questions. For one question 4 answers. But on the test page when i'm trying to select one answer for question one is selected for all question. I mean i can select only one radio button. I know that in html for create group of radio buttons they should have same names. How i can create a group of radio buttons with spring tag form?

Here test_page.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/resources/styles/style.css"/>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body onload="startTimer()">
<div id="info">
    <h3>
        Subject: <c:out value="${test.subject}"/>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        Number of questions:
        <c:out value="${test.questionNumber}"/>
    </h3>
    <h3>
        Difficulty:
        <c:out value="${test.difficulty}"/>
    </h3>
    <div id="clock">
        <p>
            <label for="timer">Time for test</label>
            <span id="timer" style="color: #4af; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;">
                <c:out value="${test.timer}"/></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test">
    <form:form action="result" commandName="result" method="post">
        <form:input type="hidden" path="testSubject" value="${test.subject}"/>
        <form:input type="hidden" path="difficulty" value="${test.difficulty}"/>
        <c:forEach items="${test.questionAnswersMap}" var="entry">
            <h4><c:out value="${entry.key}"/></h4>
            <div class="form-check">
                <ul style="list-style: none">
                    <form:radiobuttons path="answers" items="${entry.value.existingAnswers}" element="li" class="form-check-input"/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
        <button id="finish" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block">Finish</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using spring 4.
If someone knows how to solve that i will be grateful.

Comment: With your data structure is not possible to show the questions/answers and store the user responses, you should modify your object form and send a List with the objects of questionAnswersMap, then add in the path the index, in this case would be unique and you could retrieve the responses

Comment: @cralfaro, thank you so much for your help, i will try that